# A protected class member can be accessed just like a public class member in Java

Tags: java

A **protected** class member in Java by convention, can be accessed only from within the class where it is declared or from it's direct descendant inheriting class. A **protected** class member in the following example, however can be accessed from other class without using any inheritance concept in Java.

```
package classmembers;

final class Demo
{
    private int a=10;
    protected int b=20;
    public int c=30;

    public Demo(int a, int b, int c)
    {
        this.a=a;
        this.b=b;
        this.c=c;
    }

    protected void show()
    {
        System.out.println("a = "+a);
    }
}

final public class Main
{
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        Demo d=new Demo(10, 20, 30);

        //System.out.print("\n"+d.a);    Wrong, since a has private access

        d.show(); //Working, even if it is protected

        System.out.print("\n"+d.b);  //Working, even if it is protected

        System.out.print("\n"+d.c);  //Working, since it is public, obviously
    }
}
```

---

In this example, the **protected** class members **b** of type int and the method **show()** declared within the class **Demo** are being accessed through the main() method even if they are explicitly declared as **protected** and no any inheritance concept is used.

---

In such a scenario, what is the difference between a protected class member and a public class member in Java. Are they same?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

This is because protected members can also be accessed from classes in the same package. (And both `Main` and `Demo` are in the `classmembers` package.)

> *In such a scenario, what is the difference between a protected class member and a public class member in Java. Are they same?*

The modifiers only differ if the classes are of different packages.

Have a look at the table at the official tutorial: [Controlling Access to Members of a Class](http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/accesscontrol.html)

```
Modifier        Class    Package    Subclass     World
------------------------------------------------------
public            Y        Y            Y          Y  <---.
                                                          |---- difference!
protected         Y        Y            Y          N  <---'
                          ---

no modifier       Y        Y            N          N
private           Y        N            N          N
```

Answer (score 8):

The `protected` modifier ensures *package-private* access. For more information, see [Controlling Access to Members of a Class](http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/accesscontrol.html).

[image]

Answer (score 4):

protected can be accessed by class in the same package too.  That is why your example works.

Try creating a class with a main in a different package and you will not have access.

Regards